# Is Lord Grant based on an actual Jazz musician?

Tags: inspiration, rivers-of-london

In Ben Aaronovitch’s *Rivers of London* series, Peter, the main character, has a father (Lord Grant) who was repeatedly almost famous. There are enough hints and descriptions of the various events, that I’m curious if the character was based on any particular real life person. Perhaps as a nod and a wink to those in the know. Alternately, he’s just meant to be another almost was.

Word of God would be best on this, but any jazz fanatic who can make a compelling argument will also be considered.

Comment: Is the fictional character Lord Grant supposed to be an actual lord who was an almost famous Jazz musician, or an almost famous Jazz musician who used the stage name Lord Grant?  The first possibility would be a bit rarer than the second possibility.

Comment: @M.A.Golding the second. Grant is his last name, the first was because a famous jazz musician heard him play and said “Lord, that boy is good!” And so he became known as Lord Grant.